# How to create a factory method for NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I would like to create a factory method for NavigationLink:s as follows:

```
func makeNavigationLink(label: String, destination: View) -> some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: StatsView(), label: {
        Text(label)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.title)
    })
}
```

This produces an error: `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

How should this be coded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add view constraint.

```
func makeNavigationLink<Destination: View>(label: String, destination: Destination) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: StatsView(), label: {
            Text(label)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        })
    }
```