# How to pass view as Parameter in a function Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swiftui

There are several posts on how to pass a view to a struct using:

```
struct ContainerView<Content: View>: View {
let content: Content

init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
}

var body: some View {
    content
    }
}
```

But how do you pass a view as a parameter in a function?

Comment: Already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65757532/14733292, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847827/14733292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually pass a view as a generic:

```
 func functionName<T:View>(viewYouArePassing: T){}
```

Answer (score 1):

[You also can use AnyView](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122440),

```
struct Whatever {
     var view: AnyView
}

let myWhatever = Whatever(view: AnyView(CustomView))
```